# Solve $2 \log_2 5+2-x=\log_2(3^x+2^{6-x})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

What I have so far: The equation can be reduced to $\frac{50}{x}=3^x+2^{6-x}$.

Since $\frac{50}{x}<0$ for $x<0$ and $3^x+2^{6-x}\geq0$ for all x there are no negative solutions.

Also since $3^3 > 50/3$ there are no solutions greater than 3 (we can maybe use this same strategy to narrow down the possibilities even more but I don think that will help much with the problem).

You can check easily that 2 is a solution and I thought that if it were true that $3^x+2^{6-x}$ is increasing for $x>2$ then since $50/x$ is decreasing it would follow that only 2 is the only solution but the former is not true.

So any other ideas ? Keep in mind that this is an algebra problem for 11 grade so advanced techniques wont help me much but feel free to share them still. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $\frac{100}{2^x}=3^x+2^{6-x}$. That's much easier to solve.

Comment: Yes I can take it from here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$2 \log_2 5+2-x=\log_2(3^x+2^{6-x})$$

Including the factor 2.

$$ \log_2 25+2-x=\log_2(3^x+2^{6-x})$$

Seperating $2-x$

$$ 2-x=\log_2(3^x+2^{6-x})-\log_2 25$$

$\log_c(X)-\log_c(Y)=\log_c\left(\frac{X}{Y} \right)$ so

$$2-x=\log_2\left(\frac{3^x+2^{6-x}}{25} \right)$$

Removing $\log_2()$

$$\frac4{2^x}=\frac{3^x+2^{6-x}}{25}$$

Multiplying both sides by $2^x$ and $25$

$$100=6^x+2^6$$

$$100=6^x+64$$

$$36=6^x$$

$$x=2$$